# Telling the compiler that I am no longer using a namespace in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, namespaces

the syntax:

```
 using namespace x;
```

tells the compiler to find the symbols from namespace x. The situation becomes bad once you have a same symbol in two namespaces and you want to mutually use them. Is there a way to tell the compiler not to use a namespace? What I mean is something like this (namespaces x and y both have the function a)

```
using namespace x;
int k = a(); //x::a is called
drop namespace x; //imaginary syntax that I am looking for
using namespace y;
int j = a(); //y::a is called
```

"You must use scope resolution symbol '::'" is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: why don't you wanna use scope resolution ??

Comment: The library is prebuilt and I can't change the names of the functions. This is using CPU or GPU with same function names overloaded in different namespaces. Code really looks bad in near 10,000 lines always using ::!

Comment: "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this!"

Comment: Don't use `using namespace` in the first place.

Comment: What about `x::a()` then `y::a()`?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Well isn't that THE scope resolution which I just said is not the answer I am looking for?!!!

Comment: Indeed, but I wondered if you simply missed the point.

Comment: More people would be less offended if someone removes the C++ tag.

Comment: Nitpick: you ***can't*** not use scope resolution. Without _resolution_, everything is _unresolved_ by definition, and no program will ever get linked. What you meant (I think) is I don't want to do explicit namespace qualification on identifier use.

Comment: I am sorry what I meant from scope resolution was the "::". I will fix that right up.

Comment: Please kindly note that using the arrow near a comment is supposed to be a sign that the comment adds something useful to the post. I understand that my question was trivial, but please kindly do not use it as facebook like. I am also very sorry for saying this.

Comment: *"Please kindly note that using the arrow near a comment is supposed to be a sign that the comment adds something useful to the post"* - Can it be you're just upset that all those *"useless"* comments telling you to use the dreaded *"scope resolution symbol"* get *"liked"* that much? Maybe all the people supposed to use it as *"facebook like"* just think those comments do *"add something useful to the post"*?

Comment: -1 just for being completely arrogant. You have this fluffed up sense of knowing what's right, yet completely fail to understand that if this were the case you wouldn't be asking the question. You're asking the question, observer the weight of the answer: use the language tools. Either create an alias or just qualify the identifiers. It's that simple.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you don't want to use scope resolution, then create some additional scope:

```
{
    using namespace x;
    int k = a(); //x::a is called
}
{
    using namespace y;
    int j = a(); //y::a is called
}
```

I'm afraid this might turn to be worse than scope resolution, though :/

Edit:

One more thing (which I don't know if you're aware of) that might be helpful are namespace aliases. Say you've got a namespace with a disgustingly long name or multiple nested namespaces. You can shorten the name such as:

```
namespace x = very::weird::namespc::name;
namespace y = yabadabadoopdiedoo;
```

Comment: If you have a lot of calls to equally named functions so easily segregated from each other then this is probably the best.  If you only have a couple calls, I recommend just scope them explicitly those couple times.

Comment: Thanks, finally someone here knows not to answer with scope resolution which I clearly wrote in concise English! This really worked and solves my problem!

Comment: Glad it helped, just don't blame me if your coworkers diss you for it ;)

Comment: @GreenCode That's amazing when you said 'no scope resolution' jrok's answer was exactly what I thought you didn't want to use. My mistake, I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @jrok: coworkers are gonna love it ;). It would have been :: all over the code if you didn't help!

Comment: @GreenCode Isn't this manual scope resolution? You have created 2 scope blocks?

Comment: OP mush hate Krillin.  Anyway, just an advice.  If you're programming in C++, program in C++.  I would hate to be the person to maintain your code.

Comment: Dude that is opencv! that is not my code! don't use opencv then! start building machine vision from middle ages!

Comment: @GreenCode How is it OpenCV's fault that you find `::` ugly? Namespaces are there for a reason.

Comment: I just asked a question! In my opinion using ten :: in a line makes it very complicated to understand!

Comment: @GreenCode No, omitting them makes it complicated.

Comment: @GreenCode: Also, more importantly: what's with your attitude ? You chose to program in a language that you obviously don't like or accept as it is. No need to put "!" in all your sentences or to be arrogant. It's hardly our fault if you don't understand the language.

Comment: Well obviously I don't understand C. granted. but once a person uses "Please I beg you don't answer with scope resolution", you should give the man some credit. It's not like if I am not understanding C language you have problems understanding English language. Am i right?

Comment: @GreenCode Does C have namespaces now ? And you tagged this C++. And you believe those two are the same or that one is a subset of the other, then I can only advise you to stop programming until you (re)learn C++ for real.

Comment: @Rapptz: Sorry for using C. I meant C++. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: @GreenCode This is not your personal helpdesk and answers encouraging to solve this ~~problem~~ in this particular way are actively harmful to people who'll stumble upon this question later. Your English words are quite irrelevant, because it's just a sign of XY problem (i.e. you invented a solution and want to know how to implement it, but it's not the right solution in the first place).

Comment: And on the subject of "problems understanding English language", I will subtly point at my [***nitpick*** comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093226/telling-the-compiler-that-i-am-no-longer-using-a-namepsace-in-c/16093259#comment22978059_16093226) and let that be the end of this.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I didn't mean any harm to any persons knowledge and I am very sorry if I showed disrespect to anyone. I only wanted to ask if this is possible in C++. The question had a right answer in my opinion and it is the one I chose. Again, I am very sorry for my bad manners, but please understand that in my question body, I mentioned that using scope resolution is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @sehe: Thank you, I have my answer. I deeply apologize for my misbehavior. That will be the end of it.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot "drop" a namespace, however, when using namespace composition you can resolve specific ambiguities as follows:

```
namespace composite {
    using namespace x;
    using namespace y;
    using y::a; // use y::a in case of ambiguity

    void foo() {
        a(); // calls y::a
    }
}
```

Comment: @jrok [It works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=03f1ae258bf230077ce1288e6eb6056b-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: Now that's weird, maybe I'm missing something. Did you check the link in my updated comment? (i didn't downvote, btw)

Comment: You need to reduce the scope of the last using statement. [Example.](http://ideone.com/cPBNmG) Or, even better, [reduce the scope of all using directive.](http://ideone.com/5xrqO1).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, but I wonder what's the rule behind this, why doesn't it work when said in namespace scope?

Comment: IIRC it only doesn't work in the global namespace. (This feature is called 'namespace composition btw. So it makes sense..)

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Thanks, it seems to be the name of what I am looking for. Gratitude :)

Comment: Adding `using y::a` after `using namespace a` adds nothing, AFAIK. It just inserts the name `a` into the enclosing namespace, which has already happened.

Comment: @jrok: if we nest the blocks, will the symbols then be resolved with the nearest namespace all the way to the outer block? or will it be ambigious? I am just curious, not that I am trying to actually nest them.

Comment: @sehe I actually learned this technique from Bjarne's book "The C++ Programming Language". And you can see from my posted samples that it works.

Comment: @sehe Actually, I only learned about this a few weeks ago myself.

Answer (score 6):

> 2 A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace **can be used in the scope in which the
>   using-directive appears after the using-directive.** During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear
>   as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and the
>   nominated namespace. [ Note: In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”. —end
>   note ]

Thus you have to use different scopes. There is no way to unuse, after using.